# URL Encoding of Characters in a password field

Tags: iphone, post, urlencode, nslog

I am trying to pass login credentials to a PHP script that I have in my iPhone app.  When I pull a password with special characters the password is missing certain characters especially the percent sign.  I am trying to encode the text but even before I send it, the percent sign is missing.

```
//p_field is a UITextField holding the password: !@#$%^&*()
NSString *tmpPass = [p_field.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSLog(p_field.text);
NSLog(tmpPass);
```

This is what appears in the console:

```
!@#$^&*()

!@2259.719281E-314&*()
```

Is there any reason why it would be dropping the percent sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to NSLog is a format string, and '%'s have special meaning within the format string. You should instead be doing something like:

```
NSLog("p_field.text = %@", p_field.text);
NSLog("tmpPass = %@", tmpPass);
```

(the `%@` is the format string sequence for displaying an NSString.)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on [FooBabel.com](http://www.foobabel.com/apps/cs/URLCodec) and it should look like:  `%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29` encoded.